# Fire JavaScript from button inside GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a GriView and implemented RowDataBound event like below

```
  protected void gvwSearchResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
                string IdValue = gvwSearchResult.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
                Button _btnCheque = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnCheque");                  
               _btnCheque .OnClientClick = "<script type='text/javascript'>if(confirm('Do you want to continue?')){window.location='Cheque.aspx?ID=" + IdValue.ToString()+"';}</script>";
            }

    }
```

When I click on button, there is a script error thrown. any idea on my script formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is the error you are getting?
2. Try using the same without the `<script>` tag (see example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx))...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the script tags in the OnClientClick - just put the javascript directly.